# Failed to install db-dtypes in the virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip

The jupyter notebook im running demands for db-dypes package installation.
Tried the below command

```
pip install db-dtypes
```

and got the below error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command 'C:\\Users\\smg30\\datagen/Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I put everything in place, like placing the path inside environment variable(OS-windows)

```
C:\Users\smg30\datagen\Scripts\
```

and cmake is installed already.However, failing to get the job done

Comment: try: pip install cmake --no-cache-dir --prefer-binary, maybe it works. Have a look: https://github.com/scikit-build/cmake-python-distributions/issues/103

Comment: Ensure CMake is installed: ```cmake --version```

Comment: cmake is installed.

Comment: @OmerSezer that command didn't work either, same error again No Module named cmake.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates a missing dependency, specifically `cmake`. If using Linux then you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

On Windows just download  download the installer for CMake from the [official website](https://cmake.org/download/). Once downloaded and installed, make sure the path to `cmake.exe` is added to your system's PATH.On MacOS, in a terminal execute `brew install cmake`

It is best practice to use a virtual environment when working with Python projects. This ensures that packages and dependencies do not affect each other. You can create a new virtual environment using:

```
python -m venv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
```

To activate if on Linux/Windows, run `python -m venv myenv`, followed by `source myenv/bin/activate` on Linux and `myenv\Scripts\activate` on Windows

Then, try installing the packages within this virtual environment.